# Creating the links of a chain in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I am working on a project where I have to create a chain with 12 links in it. I want to create the chain out of two curved segments for the top and bottom of the link ad  two cylinders for the straight segments, I intend to use a display list to create one link and then display it over and over after applying some rotation transformations. My question is how can I construct the curved sections?

One idea was to use gluPartialDisk(); swept thru 180 degrees to construct the top and bottom portions. is there a more efficient way of doing this?

PS: Forgot to mention that this was to be in 3D, I guess gluPartialDisk() will not work in this case. I want to use basic OpenGL shapes to create this rather than using 3D modeler, this way I will be able to learn more about OpenGL.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using a 3D modeller. In fact, you will probably learn more about opengl after writing a model parser, as well as it being useful in many projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to use display lists, `gluPartialDisk()` is probably efficient enough (and it's not worth the effort to implement it yourself).

However, there are methods that are even faster than using display lists themselves. I would highly suggest using vertex arrays or vertex buffer objects.